# Best Practices for re-scheduling and starting the specific timer job using code

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs, farm-solution

I have a situation where some of the code needs to re-schedule the specific timer job and start it according to new schedule. The timer jobs actually writes (need permissions) into the SharePoint configuration database.

I know it's a bit tricky situation because the code needs to be executed and must have the Farm administrator permission for manipulation of SharePoint configuration Database. We also know that our majority of code runs under the application pool account and of course we don't wanna promote our application pool account as a Farm Administrator account (as per Best practices).

What are the alternative scenarios we have at the moment?

Comment: Are you talking about restarting the timer service, or just specific timer jobs?

Comment: I'm talking about resetting the timer job service in general.

Comment: Ok, so does the restart need to be triggered by some event in SharePoint, or could it be done on a scheduled basis?

Comment: actually, there is a Web part (UI) from where we are supposed to reset a specific timer job, either to reset it or set a new scheduled time.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Sounds like you want to manipulate individual timer jobs, not restart the timer service. Just to clarify, timer jobs in SharePoint all run within the context of a windows service (called the SharePoint Timer Service). While you can use the SharePoint API to create/delete/reschedule individual timer jobs, it doesn't make sense to use the term 'reset' a specific timer job.

Comment: Sorry Paul for confusion, what I meant is to re-schedule a specific timer job service, and that timer job is also writing into the SharePoint configuration database.

Comment: No probs see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a web part UI for manipulating timer job schedules in SharePoint 2007, then I'd say the best practice would be to have the web part running on a page that is hosted by the Central administration site. After all such a task is an administrative task.

If the web part is in fact in the central admin site, and the logged in user is an administrator, then it should have the necessary permissions to write to the config db.

Note: In SharePoint 2010, this sort of functionality is already built in to central admin

Comment: You meant deploying the Web part on the Central Admin. We are supposed to deploy the Web Part to other Web application which is being used by normal users. I think Central Admin Web application pool account is also the Farm administrator and I think running the code with elevate privileges will not be an issue.

Comment: That's right. Someone else may be able to offer a different view, but my opinion is that the concept of allowing 'normal users' to carry out administrative tasks would be a violation of best practices.

Comment: What I meant was deploying the Web part on the Central Admin. We are supposed to deploy the Web Part to other Web application which is being used by normal users. I think deploying the Web part on Central Admin and running the code with elevate privileges will not be an issue. Because, application pool account for CA is also the Farm administrator and it is easy to write to configuration DB

Comment: Yes, I meant deploying the web part to central admin. Remember you are asking about best practices, and having this type of web part hosted in a normal web application, where normal users can use it would not be a best pratice.

Comment: Yes, I agree but there is no official documentation existing for such best practices or is there any documentation? I haven't found it myself.

Comment: No, I don't know of any documentation on this. I've based my answer on common sense ;-)

Comment: Let the common sense prevails then :D :D